# Closure and capturing local variable in a loop

Tags: c#, closures

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IRunnable runnable = new Runnable();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            RunIt(runnable);
        }

    }

    public static void RunIt(IRunnable runnable)
    {
        var context = new Context();
        context.Id = runnable.RunAsync((id,result)=>{
            //context.Id will always match "id" here?
            context.Result = result; // can I assume here that this is the same context?
        });
    }


    public interface IRunnable
    {
        int RunAsync(Action<string,string> successHandler);
    }

    public class Runnable : IRunnable
    {
       private Random _random = new Random();

        public string RunAsync(Action<string,string> successHandler)
        {

            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Task.Run(()=>
             {
               Thread.Sleep(_random.Next(0,1000));
                successHandler(guid, "result")
             });
            return guid;
        }
    }

      public class Context
    {
        public string Id {get;set;}
        public string Result{get;set;}
     }


}
```

In this example I'm running function `RunIt` in a loop. `RunIt` starts a process asynchronously and assign anonymous handler when it's done. In the same function we have a context variable which will be captured by anonymous lambda. My question is simple - can I assume that captured context will always match the result? My concern here is that I'm running it 10 times which means successHandler will be called 10 times in unordered manner. Is there a separate version of anonymous function per each context?

Long story short -  will `context.Id` always match successHandler "id" in anonymous function?

Comment: No, of course it wouldn't.  Why would you expect it to?  You CLEARLY return a new Guid that has nothing to do with the successHandler parameter.  Why would you expect it to match?

Comment: @DavidL it does match because I return this guid and assign it to the context and asynchronously later on I call successHandler with the same guid.

Comment: None of that is apparent in your question.  That is all missing context.  This question is not answerable as is.

Comment: @DavidL What? The commented line between creating guid and returning guid should explain everything. This guid is returned in the function and used in successHandler.

Comment: You are asking for a ***definitive*** answer based on a ***non-definitive*** comment.  No one can see the code represented by the comment.  As a result, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: @DavidL I have edited the code. Now it should be understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question was downvoted but I'll answer it anyway. The answer is yes, `Context` variable will be captured separately per each iteration.